# Is XFS supported as the root file system on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: server, filesystem, xfs

Does Ubuntu Server 18.04 support XFS for the root filesystem? The Ubuntu wiki says

> GRUB-Support is in an early stage, therefore using xfs as boot-filesystem can be a bad idea

I plan to use a separate 1GB `ext4` partition for `/boot`. Since all other filesystems are mounted on the root filesystem, will an XFS root affect grub?